# Select rows where sum of a column equals a fixed value in R

Tags: r, algorithm, subset-sum

I would like to get one (or all) possible combination of rows where sum of quantity column equals 20

here an example :

```
structure(list(id = 1:10, quantity = c(11L, 1L, 4L, 12L, 19L, 10L, 3L, 13L, 16L, 14L)), class ="data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))

id quantity
1   11          
2   1           
3   4           
4   12          
5   19          
6   10          
7   3           
8   13          
9   16          
10  14
```

desired output (one possible set) :

```
id quantity
3   4           
7   3           
8   13
```

or

```
id quantity
 2  1           
 5  19
```

Comment: Could you add what has failed?

Comment: What are some rules regarding these combinations?

Comment: No fixed rule, i just need any combination that satistfies sum(quantity)==20

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858688/find-all-combinations-of-numbers-that-sum-to-a-target) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905044/finding-all-combinations-of-four-numbers-that-equal-a-sum-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another base R solution by defining a ***recursive function*** `subsetSum` (I guess this would be faster since it avoids checking through all combinations)

```
subsetSum <- function(v, target, r = c()) {
    if (sum(r) == target) {
        return(list(r))
    }
    unlist(lapply(seq_along(v), function(k) subsetSum(v[-(1:k)], target, c(r, v[k]))), recursive = FALSE)
}
```

Then, when running

```
target <- 20
lst <- subsetSum(setNames(df$quantity, seq(nrow(df))), target)
res <- Map(function(v) df[as.integer(names(v)), ], lst)
```

you will get

```
> res
[[1]]
  id quantity
2  2        1
3  3        4
4  4       12
7  7        3

[[2]]
  id quantity
2  2        1
5  5       19

[[3]]
  id quantity
2  2        1
7  7        3
9  9       16

[[4]]
  id quantity
3  3        4
7  7        3
8  8       13

[[5]]
  id quantity
3  3        4
9  9       16
```

---

If you want only one of the subset sum which reaches the given value, you can try `subsetsum` from package `adagio`

```
library(adagio)
target <- 20
res <- df[subsetsum(df$quantity,target)$inds,]
```

which gives

```
> res
  id quantity
2  2        1
5  5       19
```

Comment: I like your solution, how can i get it to stop looping at the first combination that satisfies the sum condition ? i added a break instruction in the if statement but not working (i have to loop it over 3000 products each having at least quantity array of length of 100)

Comment: @Seif I don't think you are able to break into the recursion and extract the first combination. Instead, you can use function `subsetsum` from package `adagio` to make it. See my updates.

Comment: What would happen if no combination sum the target? There is any solution to find the nearest combination to the target?

Comment: @kikusanchez You can specify your question with an example and post it rather than a comment

Comment: Ok @ThomasIsCoding, I'll do it!

Answer (score 4):

In case the combination are ok:

```
target <- 20
lapply(seq_len(sum(cumsum(sort(x$quantity)) <= target)), function(n) {
  y <- combn(x$quantity, n)
  y[,colSums(y) == target]
})
#[[1]]
#integer(0)
#
#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]   19   16
#
#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]    3    3
#[3,]   16   13
#
#[[4]]
#[1]  1  4 12  3
```

...and to get the row:

```
lapply(seq_len(sum(cumsum(sort(x$quantity)) <= target)), function(n) {
  y <- combn(x$quantity, n)
  y <- y[,colSums(y) == target, drop = FALSE]
  if(length(y) > 0) {apply(y, 2, match, x$quantity)}
})
#[[1]]
#NULL
#
#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    3
#[2,]    5    9
#
#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    3
#[2,]    7    7
#[3,]    9    8
#
#[[4]]
#     [,1]
#[1,]    2
#[2,]    3
#[3,]    4
#[4,]    7
```

... and somehow like the expected output:

```
lapply(seq_len(sum(cumsum(sort(x$quantity)) <= target)), function(n) {
  y <- combn(x$quantity, n)
  y <- y[,colSums(y) == target, drop = FALSE]
  if(length(y) > 0) {apply(y, 2, function(i) {x[match(i, x$quantity),]})}
})
#[[1]]
#NULL
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#  id quantity
#2  2        1
#5  5       19
#
#[[2]][[2]]
#  id quantity
#3  3        4
#9  9       16
#
#
#[[3]]
#[[3]][[1]]
#  id quantity
#2  2        1
#7  7        3
#9  9       16
#
#[[3]][[2]]
#  id quantity
#3  3        4
#7  7        3
#8  8       13
#
#
#[[4]]
#[[4]][[1]]
#  id quantity
#2  2        1
#3  3        4
#4  4       12
#7  7        3
```

Data:

```
x <- structure(list(id = 1:10, quantity = c(11L, 1L, 4L, 12L, 19L, 10L, 3L, 13L, 16L
  , 14L)), class ="data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))
```

Comment: How can i get the associated ids ?

Comment: I have made an update which returns the rows - as originally asked.