Checking if a set of numbers can be added up to a given value
I have a table like this:
set.seed(123)
random_table <- data.frame(
  Column1 = sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE),
  Column2 = sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE),
  Column3 = sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE),
  Column4 = sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE),
  Column5 = sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE)
)


 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
       3       5       5       3       9
       3       4       3       8       3
      10       6       9      10       4
       2       9       9       7       1
       6      10       9      10       7

I want to make a function that checks if "n" numbers from this table can sum to some value "m". When this is possible, I want to record all such combinations (else NULL).
I tried to write a function to do this using the combinat library:
library(combinat)

    find_combinations <- function(table, num, target_sum) {

    combinations <- combn(as.vector(as.matrix(table)), num)

    valid_combinations <- list()
    valid_cells <- list()

    for (i in 1:ncol(combinations)) {
        if (sum(combinations[, i]) == target_sum) {
            valid_combinations <- append(valid_combinations, list(combinations[, i]))
        
            cells <- c()
            for (value in combinations[, i]) {
            cell <- which(table == value, arr.ind = TRUE)[1, ]
            cells <- c(cells, paste0(LETTERS[cell[2]], cell[1]))
        }
        valid_cells <- append(valid_cells, list(cells))
    }
}

if (length(valid_combinations) > 0) {
    result <- data.frame(
        id = seq_along(valid_combinations),
        sum = rep(target_sum, length(valid_combinations)),
        numbers_selected = sapply(valid_combinations, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ",")),
        cells = sapply(valid_cells, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ","))
    )
} else {
    result <- data.frame(
        id = NA,
        sum = NA,
        numbers_selected = NA,
        cells = NA
    )
}

return(result)

}
I then called the function for a specific example and removed all duplicates (relative to the cells column):
result <- find_combinations(random_table, num = 4, target_sum = 19)

result$sorted_cells <- sapply(strsplit(result$cells, ","), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = ","))
result <- result[!duplicated(result$sorted_cells), ]
result$sorted_cells <- NULL

result$id <- seq_len(nrow(result))

The output looks like this:
 id sum numbers_selected       cells
  1  19         3,3,10,3 A1,A1,A3,A1
  2  19          3,3,6,7 A1,A1,A5,D4
  3  19          3,3,5,8 A1,A1,B1,D2
  4  19          3,3,4,9 A1,A1,B2,B4
  5  19         3,10,2,4 A1,A3,A4,B2

Are there any standard ways to do this in R (ex: Finding all possible combinations of numbers from a vector to reach a given sum (No repetitions), Getting all the combination of numbers from a list that would sum to a specific number)? Or do we really have to write a function?

I think this is kind of "subset-sum problem". You can take a look at the answers https://stackoverflow.com/q/61770621/12158757

Just wondering, what do you mean by return all combinations? For example, there are 40 different ways to choose 3,3,10,3, none of them using the same set of cells in the table, and all of them using distinct cells.  If you allow cells to be selected more than once, then the number is much larger, but your result shows only one combination (and that combination uses A1 three times).

langtang: thank you for pointing this out...

@ thomas: here is the new version of the older question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78839974/summing-nodes-in-a-network

This is a restricted subset sum problem. Take a look at RcppAlgos::partitionsGeneral (also see this vignette).
library(RcppAlgos)

result <- partitionsGeneral(unlist(random_table), 4, target = 19)
dim(result)
#> [1] 328   4

all(rowSums(result) == 19)
#> [1] TRUE

A function to get indices:
f <- function(df, num, target_sum, linear = TRUE) {
  x <- unlist(df, 1, 1)
  vals <- unique(partitionsGeneral(x, num, target = target_sum))
  idx <- array(split(seq_along(x), x)[as.character(vals)], dim(vals))
  out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(asplit(idx, 1), comboGrid, repetition = FALSE))
  if (!(linear || is.vector(df))){
    out[] <- outer(1:nrow(df), LETTERS[1:ncol(df)], \(a, b) paste0(b, a))[out]
  }
  out
}

Testing:
result_idx <- f(random_table, 4, 19)
dim(result_idx)
#> [1] 552   4

# check that each row corresponds to a set of indices of values that sum correctly
x <- result_idx
x[] <- unlist(df, 1, 1)[result_idx]
all(rowSums(x) == 19)
#> [1] TRUE

f(random_table, 4, 19, FALSE)[1:5,]
#>      Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
#> [1,] "E4" "A4" "A5" "A3"
#> [2,] "E4" "A4" "A5" "B5"
#> [3,] "E4" "A4" "A5" "D3"
#> [4,] "E4" "A4" "A5" "D5"
#> [5,] "E4" "A4" "B3" "A3"

Note that for this example, result and result_idx don't have the same number of rows. partitionsGeneral stops early once it has identified all unique outputs (see the comment below from the package's author, Joseph Wood).

Great! I was thinking if there is any package can simply solves the problem, then your answer tells, cheers!

@ jblood94: thank you! but how do I list the numbers that match this condition ?

@farrow90 each row in result is the combinations of numbers

@farrow90, result contains the numbers. Each row is a unique subset (although, since there are duplicate values in the table, there will be sets of duplicate rows). Do you mean the indices of the numbers?

thanks everyone - I just meant for cells indices

this looks great @jblood94  Why does result only contain three rows for 4,4,5,6? Shouldn't there be four?  (B2,E3,B1,A5; B2,E3,C1,A5; B3,E3,B1,B3, and B2,E3,C1,E3?  What am I missing here?

I was wondering the same thing. See the update. Perhaps @JosephWood has some insight as to the behavior of partitionsGeneral when dealing with duplicate values.

@jblood94, great answer. Since there are duplicate values, we need think about multisets. There are a couple of ways to do this, but the easiest way is to take advantage of the S3 method for tables. E.g. wrap table around unlist(random_table). Now we are left with a matching problem.

Oh wow! I just noticed your use of comboGrid. Removing my answer.

You've probably noticed that's what I did. The question is why result and result_index have differing number of rows.

Put simply, since you are passing a vector that is not isomorphic to vector 1:n for some n, the algorithm defaults to a more general algorithm for partitioning a number assuming distinct input. With these assumptions, the algo will stop early and not get all of the results but will definitely get all unique results. One thing to keep in mind with all of these algorithms is that the individual numbers are not considered different if their values are not different regardless of their names. I hope this clarifies.

In base R, it might be fun if you implement a custom function in a recursion manner

f <- function(tgt, n, dat = random_table) {
  v <- unlist(dat)
  k <- seq_along(v)
  helper <- function(tgt, n, idx = k) {
    if (n == 1 && any(tgt == v)) {
      return(as.list(idx[tgt == v]))
    }
    if ((n == 0 && tgt > 0) || (n > 0 && tgt <= 0) || (n == 1 && !any(tgt == v))) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    unique(
      unlist(
      lapply(idx, \(i) {
        lapply(helper(tgt - v[i], n - 1), \(u) c(i, u))
      }),
      recursive = FALSE
    ))
  }

  combs <- helper(tgt, n)
  loc <- paste0(head(LETTERS, ncol(dat))[col(dat)], row(dat))
  do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(combs, \(j) {
      data.frame(
        sum = sum(v[j]),
        number_selected = toString(v[j]),
        cells = toString(loc[j])
      )
    })
  )
}

and you can run res <- f(19, 4) and will see
> head(res, 20)
   sum number_selected          cells
1   19     3, 3, 3, 10 A1, A1, A1, A3
2   19     3, 3, 3, 10 A1, A1, A1, B5
3   19     3, 3, 3, 10 A1, A1, A1, D3
4   19     3, 3, 3, 10 A1, A1, A1, D5
5   19     3, 3, 3, 10 A1, A1, A2, A3
6   19     3, 3, 3, 10 A1, A1, A2, B5
7   19     3, 3, 3, 10 A1, A1, A2, D3
8   19     3, 3, 3, 10 A1, A1, A2, D5
9   19     3, 3, 10, 3 A1, A1, A3, A1
10  19     3, 3, 10, 3 A1, A1, A3, A2
11  19     3, 3, 10, 3 A1, A1, A3, C2
12  19     3, 3, 10, 3 A1, A1, A3, D1
13  19     3, 3, 10, 3 A1, A1, A3, E2
14  19      3, 3, 6, 7 A1, A1, A5, D4
15  19      3, 3, 6, 7 A1, A1, A5, E5
16  19      3, 3, 5, 8 A1, A1, B1, D2
17  19      3, 3, 4, 9 A1, A1, B2, B4
18  19      3, 3, 4, 9 A1, A1, B2, C3
19  19      3, 3, 4, 9 A1, A1, B2, C4
20  19      3, 3, 4, 9 A1, A1, B2, C5


I love these recursive algos. I notice you didn't use Recall... is it because helper is nested in f?

@JosephWood thank you. Recall can work with for loops, but unfortunately not with lapply

Given jblood94 excellent answer, this may not be of any added value, but I wrote the following, which provides the cell indices:

library(data.table)

names(random_table) <- LETTERS[1:5]

f <- \(tbl,num,target) {
  k <- combn(unlist(tbl),4,simplify = F)
  k <- k[sapply(k,\(i) sum(i)==target)]
  rbindlist(lapply(seq_along(k), \(i) {
    data.table(i, ns = k[[i]],cells = names(k[[i]]))[order(i,ns,cells), lapply(.SD, \(s) paste(s,collapse=",")), i]
  }))
}

f(random_table, 4, 19)

Output:
         i       ns       cells
     <int>   <char>      <char>
  1:     1 3,3,3,10 A1,A2,C2,A3
  2:     2 3,3,3,10 A1,A2,D1,A3
  3:     3 3,3,3,10 A1,A2,E2,A3
  4:     4  3,3,6,7 A1,A2,A5,D4
  5:     5  3,3,6,7 A1,A2,A5,E5
 ---                           
548:   548  1,3,7,8 E4,D1,E5,D2
549:   549  3,3,4,9 D1,E2,E3,E1
550:   550  1,3,7,8 E4,E2,D4,D2
551:   551  1,3,7,8 E4,E2,E5,D2
552:   552  1,4,7,7 E4,E3,D4,E5

(Also, note that my output is a bit longer than the above answer, but I can't yet see a problem with what I'm producing.)

I had a unique in the wrong spot. The length of the output of my function matches yours.

@ langtang: thank you! I wish I could upvote your answer but i dont have enough reputation yet :(

Another relatively fast way using combinations from gtools
library(gtools)

names(random_table) <- LETTERS[1:5]

nms <- names(random_table)

getDesSum <- function(dat, out, tsum){
  vect <- as.vector(t(dat)); row <- nrow(dat); col <- ncol(dat)
  data.frame(do.call(rbind,
    apply(combinations(row*col, out, 1:(row*col)), 1, \(x){
      res <- vect[x]; Sum <- sum(res)
      if(Sum == tsum){
        list(Sum = Sum,
             numbers_selected = res,
             cells = paste0(nms[floor((x-1) / col)+1], ((x-1) %% col)+1))
      }
    })))}

output (limited with head)
head(getDesSum(random_table, 4, 19))
  Sum numbers_selected          cells
1  19       3, 5, 5, 6 A1, A2, A3, C2
2  19       3, 5, 5, 6 A1, A2, A3, E1
3  19       3, 5, 3, 8 A1, A2, A4, B4
4  19       3, 5, 9, 2 A1, A2, A5, D1
5  19       3, 5, 3, 8 A1, A2, B1, B4
6  19       3, 5, 4, 7 A1, A2, B2, D4

nrow(getDesSum(random_table, 4, 19))
[1] 552


thank you! i i wish i could upvote your answer but i dont have enough reputation to do so :(

currently I am working on this question ... do you have any ideas about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78839974/summing-nodes-in-a-network

@farrow90 No worries, but thanks for letting me know! Appreciate it!

@farrow90 Unfortunately I am not a graph expert... but I'll take a look.
