Listing all neighbors of a graph in R
I have this graph in R:
library(igraph)

set.seed(123)

n <- 20
g <- sample_gnm(n, m = n * 2, directed = FALSE)

while (!is_connected(g)) {
    # Find disconnected components
    components <- components(g)
    
    
    for (i in 2:components$no) {
        from <- sample(which(components$membership == i), 1)
        to <- sample(which(components$membership == 1), 1)
        g <- add_edges(g, c(from, to))
    }
}

g <- simplify(g, remove.multiple = FALSE, remove.loops = TRUE)

V(g)$weight <- runif(vcount(g))

layout <- layout_with_fr(g)


plot(g, layout = layout, edge.arrow.size = 0.1, 
     vertex.label = V(g)$name, vertex.size = 15, 
     vertex.label.color = "black", edge.curved = 0,
     vertex.color = "white", edge.color = "black")


I have this R code that lists all the neighbors of each node:
get_neighbors <- function(graph, vertex) {
    neighbors(graph, vertex)
}

neighbor_list <- list()

for (v in V(g)) {
    neighbor_list[[as.character(v)]] <- get_neighbors(g, v)
}

for (v in names(neighbor_list)) {
    cat("Neighbors of vertex", v, ":", neighbor_list[[v]], "\n")
}

Suppose I want to find out the first degree neighbors of each node starting from a specific node, e.g. (goes in order):

list neighbors of node 16 : 6, 19
list neighbors of node  6: 14, 18, 19, 16
list neighbors of node 19: 16, 6, 5
list neighbors of node 14: etc
etc.

I have this function which lists the first degree neighbors of each node (starting from an initial node):
explore_first_degree_neighbors <- function(graph, start_node, max_steps = 5) {
    visited <- vector("logical", vcount(graph))
    queue <- c(start_node)
    results <- list()
    step <- 1
    
    while (length(queue) > 0 && step <= max_steps) {
        current_node <- queue[1]
        queue <- queue[-1]
        
        if (!visited[current_node]) {
            visited[current_node] <- TRUE
            
            neighbors <- as.numeric(neighbors(graph, current_node))
            results[[as.character(current_node)]] <- neighbors
            
            cat("Neighbors of node", current_node, ":", neighbors, "\n")
            
            # Add unvisited neighbors to the queue
            queue <- c(queue, neighbors[!visited[neighbors]])
            
            step <- step + 1
        }
    }
    
    return(results)
}

start_node <- 16
max_steps <- 100

cat("Starting exploration from node", start_node, "for", max_steps, "steps:\n\n")
exploration_results <- explore_first_degree_neighbors(g, start_node, max_steps)

The results look like this:
  Neighbors of node 16 : 6 19 
Neighbors of node 6 : 9 14 16 19 
Neighbors of node 19 : 4 6 16 
Neighbors of node 9 : 1 5 6 11 17 
Neighbors of node 14 : 4 5 6 8 11 12 
Neighbors of node 4 : 3 8 10 14 15 17 19 
Neighbors of node 1 : 3 5 8 9 
Neighbors of node 5 : 1 2 8 9 14 20 
Neighbors of node 11 : 9 10 13 14 
Neighbors of node 17 : 2 3 4 7 9 18 
Neighbors of node 8 : 1 4 5 14 15 
Neighbors of node 12 : 7 14 15 20 
Neighbors of node 3 : 1 4 17 
Neighbors of node 10 : 2 4 7 11 
Neighbors of node 15 : 2 4 8 12 
Neighbors of node 2 : 5 10 15 17 
Neighbors of node 20 : 5 12 13 
Neighbors of node 13 : 11 20 
Neighbors of node 7 : 10 12 17 
Neighbors of node 18 : 17 

The problem is that when I reach node 18, the function naturally stops (even though the maximum number of steps has still not been reached). I want to change this function so that when I encounter a boundary node (e.g. node 18) - the function will starting moving backwards and listing the neighbors in the other direction.
Can someone please suggest how I can modify this function to do this?


I don't understand "I want to change this function so that when I encounter a boundary node (e.g. node 18) - the function will starting moving backwards and listing the neighbors in the other direction.". What is the expected output?

From 18, it would go to 17  .... from 17 it would look at (7,2,4,3) , from 3 it would look at  (17, 4,1) etc

from 17, why it would look at (7, 2, 4, 3), rather than (2, 3, 4 ,7, 9, 18)?

@ThomasIsCoding : actually, I think your logic makes more sense ... you are correct

I think this problem involves combining backtracking and depth first search together?

Sorry that I don’t follow the logic in your question

@ThomasIsCoding : my apologies for the poor explanation

Maybe I will try to explain it like this:

Imagine person16 talks to person6 and person19 . Then, Person6 then talks to persons (9 ,14 16, 19). then, Person 19 talks to  persons (4, 6 ,16 ) .  Person 9 talks to persons (1, 5 6, 11 ,17 ) etc etc

When we get to person17, person17 talks to persons ( 2, 3 ,4 ,7 ,9 ,18 ) . Person18 talks back to Person17 , and the cycle continues

I am trying to make a scenario to represent how different people in a network would talk to each other.

Probably this is what you are after
root <- "18"
lapply(
    seq.int(diameter(g)),
    \(k) {
        ego(g, nodes = root, order = k, mindist = k)[[1]]
    }
)

which gives
[[1]]
+ 1/20 vertex, from 77b07cd:
[1] 17

[[2]]
+ 5/20 vertices, from 77b07cd:
[1] 2 3 4 7 9

[[3]]
+ 10/20 vertices, from 77b07cd:
 [1]  5 10 15  1  8 14 19 12  6 11

[[4]]
+ 3/20 vertices, from 77b07cd:
[1] 20 16 13


thank you so much ... I am not sure if this fully corresponds to my question ... I created an animation in R (see the update to my question) ... I am trying to represent a message being passed around the network ... thank you so much for all your help
